# Windows 7 Android AVD emulator crashes on launch

Tags: eclipse, debugging, android-emulator, eclipse-plugin, android-virtual-device

I have installed the latest version of ADT (Android Developer Tools Build: v21.1.0-569685) and eclipse 3.8. I followed the instructions (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#Emulator) to start the Hello World example but the AVD crashes on start, with no error messages in the console.

I tried that and even lower RAM to 40M but still no luck. I tried all kinds of combinations of RAM and resolution (lowered resolution to 480 x 800 hdpi), camera settings, enabling "Run as Admin". It just crashes w/ a message "emulator-arm.exe has stopped working". The console doesn't show any error message.

I have tried many solutions that came up on Google but no dice; plus a lot of them are very old posts. Please help!

Please see screen shot of my configurations and crash message here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNFae.jpg

```
My machine: 
Win 7 64
RAM: 8GB
Processor:  AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 
Graphics card:  ATI Radeon HD 5450
```

This is what I see when it crashes:
emulator-arm.exe has stopped working

problem details:

```
    Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: emulator-arm.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    5111a505
  Fault Module Name:    atioglxx.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.14.10.9232
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4b208022
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000b212
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I tried running "adb logcat" and screen said "waiting for device". I started Eclipse and started AVD from AVD manager. It crashed again but "adb logcat" still said waiting for device.

Is it possibly a hardware issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed latest driver/software from ATI and everything worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to debug any given Android instance, from both real devices or from the AVDs, use `adb logcat`, other than that, your question it's really without any specific detail that can help with this.

Comment: I tried that but it just said waiting for device. Then I started Eclipse and ran AVD. It crashed again but "adb logcat" still said waiting for device. Thanks.